# Calling scrapy script as in a node.js API using spawn

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, spawn, scrapy-pipeline

I am calling a spider script using spawn which is storing data into database using pipelines.
The problem is that the spawn function is just calling the spider code and it is not storing the data into database. May be the pipeline script is not getting called.
How should i solve this ?

Comment: Are you talking about nodejs?

Comment: yes i am calling a scrapy sitemap spider from nodejs

Comment: This is probably a node question rather than a scrapy one.